# Book recommendation for second look at GR

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

Between Hawking & Ellis and Wald, which one would be the better choice to follow up a graduate-level course in GR (based off of Carroll's book)?

If not either of those two, does anyone have any suggestions? I'm interested in those two not only because of the physics they present but also because of their rigor (I'm a post-grad mathematician).

Comment: I hear that Kip Thorne's book contains the entirety of human knowledge on GR

Comment: @inertialobserver, is that the one which was co-authored by Wheeler?  And is the size of a telephone directory for a  large city? I have heard it is the definitive work in that field- but it requires an effortless facility in math to master. Which I lack...

Comment: @nielsnielsen interesting.. I didn't know that

Comment: Using a pulley and lever arrangement, I picked up a copy of Wheeler & Thorne off the shelf of a used bookstore once and gave it a go. Sadly, I lowered it back into position and walked briskly away, hoping no one noticed...